# Unnecessary free space under the figure

Tags: plotting

Here is the data

```
r = {0.001`, 0.002`, 0.003`, 0.004`, 0.005`, 0.006`, 0.007`, 0.008`,  0.009`, 0.01`, 0.02`, 0.03`, 0.04`, 0.05`, 0.06`, 0.07`, 0.08`, 0.09`, 0.1`, 0.11`, 0.12`, 0.13`, 0.14`, 0.15`, 0.16`, 0.17`, 0.18`, 0.19`, 0.2`, 0.21`, 0.22`, 0.23`, 0.24`, 0.25`, 0.26`, 0.27`, 0.28`, 0.29`, 0.3`, 0.31`, 0.32`, 0.33`, 0.34`, 0.35000000000000003`, 0.36`, 0.37`, 0.38`, 0.39`, 0.4`, 0.41000000000000003`, 0.42`, 0.43`, 0.44`, 0.45`, 0.46`, 0.47000000000000003`, 0.48`, 0.49`, 0.5};

n3 = {{1.4960000030035049`*^-6, {x -> 
  999.0009966928285`}}, {5.968000096224024`*^-6, {x -> 
  499.00199987439606`}}, {0.000013392000731551518`, {x -> 
  332.3363327441145`}}, {0.000023744003086335785`, {x -> 
  249.00399889365764`}}, {0.000037000009429685865`, {x -> 
  199.00499999474374`}}, {0.00005313602349128859`, {x -> 
  165.67266768634502`}}, {0.00007212805083274566`, {x -> 
  141.86414284567027`}}, {0.0000939520992214282`, {x -> 
  124.0079998367379`}}, {0.00011858417900684825`, {x -> 
  110.12015572505128`}}, {0.00014600030349954553`, {x -> 
  99.01000000005972`}}, {0.0005680098238822434`, {x -> 
  49.01999855150202`}}, {0.0012420754484492498`, {x -> 
  32.36333334291967`}}, {0.0021443215052007127`, {x -> 
  24.039999973339363`}}, {0.0032509920019840165`, {x -> 
  19.05000000136416`}}, {0.004538495290016105`, {x -> 
  15.726666811216605`}}, {0.005983451076847356`, {x -> 
  13.355714260596232`}}, {0.0075627396887612`, {x -> 
  11.579999999066318`}}, {0.009253553456018731`, {x -> 
  10.201111120900967`}}, {0.011033450066417084`, {x -> 
  9.10000000036963`}}, {0.012880407703534151`, {x -> 
  8.200909091052889`}}, {0.014772881756010766`, {x -> 
  7.453333434996127`}}, {0.016689862853558796`, {x -> 
  6.822307687834688`}}, {0.018610935954393268`, {x -> 
  6.28285714334217`}}, {0.020516340177831063`, {x -> 
  5.816666666690064`}}, {0.022387029045274585`, {x -> 
  5.410000001592913`}}, {0.024204730763141752`, {x -> 
  5.0523529431740135`}}, {0.025952008152981064`, {x -> 
  4.735555556421577`}}, {0.027612317807515496`, {x -> 
  4.45315789829798`}}, {0.029170068027210866`, {x -> 
  4.199999981964795`}}, {0.03061067507069372`, {x -> 
  3.971904790992755`}}, {0.03192061723448199`, {x -> 
  3.765454546256392`}}, {0.03308748626357963`, {x -> 
  3.5778260869557714`}}, {0.0341000355850353`, {x -> 
  3.4066666669048375`}}, {0.034948224852071`, {x -> 
  3.249999992103129`}}, {0.035623260287300396`, {x -> 
  3.106153846155339`}}, {0.03611763032028578`, {x -> 
  2.9737037043273804`}}, {0.036425136027566196`, {x -> 
  2.851428648150267`}}, {0.03654091590259048`, {x -> 
  2.7382758620755547`}}, {0.0364614645088929`, {x -> 
  2.633333270730463`}}, {0.03618464460242876`, {x -> 
  2.535806436294804`}}, {0.035709692348225436`, {x -> 
  2.444999998374157`}}, {0.03503721530224885`, {x -> 
  2.3603030302440335`}}, {0.0341691828813894`, {x -> 
  2.2811764912948767`}}, {0.033108909102334494`, {x -> 
  2.2071428572515583`}}, {0.03186102743331842`, {x -> 
  2.137777781741462`}}, {0.030431457670689332`, {x -> 
  2.072702702705097`}}, {0.028827364824156876`, {x -> 
  2.0115789473684056`}}, {0.027057110069636847`, {x -> 
  1.9541025638606457`}}, {0.02513019390581711`, {x -> 
  1.9000000000132595`}}, {0.023057191728931836`, {x -> 
  1.849024395200292`}}, {0.02084968211861643`, {x -> 
  1.800952380991424`}}, {0.018520168205003684`, {x -> 
  1.7555814020049791`}}, {0.01608199256224041`, {x -> 
  1.7127272745624744`}}, {0.013549246145185934`, {x -> 
  1.6722222222225294`}}, {0.010936671853071345`, {x -> 
  1.633913043547786`}}, {0.008259563365245526`, {x -> 
  1.5976595805307552`}}, {0.005533659948809222`, {x -> 
  1.5633333337955346`}}, {0.002775037985016715`, {x -> 
  1.5308163306656686`}}, {0, {x -> 1.5}}};

 ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{r, n3[[All, 1]]}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 0.04}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}, {Green, Thick}}, BaseStyle -> 28, AspectRatio -> .7, GridLines -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], AxesLabel -> {Style[\[Theta], FontSize -> 28], Style["\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalL]\), \\(\*SubscriptBox[x,min]\),\(K\)]", FontSize -> 28]}, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Style["\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalL]\), \\(\*SubscriptBox[x,min]\),\(3\)]", FontSize -> 28], Style["\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalL]\), \\(\*SubscriptBox[x,min]\),\(5\)]", FontSize -> 28], Style["\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalL]\), \\(\*SubscriptBox[x,min]\),\(7\)]", FontSize -> 28], Style["\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalL]\), \(\*SubscriptBox[x,min]\),\(9\)]", FontSize -> 28]}, LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, FrameStyle -> LightGray] &)], {Left, Top}], AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], AspectRatio -> .7, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

It seems there is no problem here but actually there is. If you change ListLinePlot to ListLogPlot, there is no problem..

The problem is that there is a big free space under the figure if ListLinePlot is used. I want to use ListLinePlot, but I dont want to have a free space under the image.

Why is there a free space under the image? Is there a simple solution?

Comment: If you are ok with rasterizing the plot then you can use `ImageCrop`.

Comment: What is `r`?  You could have just posted `n3[[All, 1]]` instead of `n3`.

Comment: sorry everyone. I totally missed the "r". Please see the edited question.

Comment: In v9 everything looks OK. Is this a v10 thing?

Comment: @belisarius v9, winxp 32bits. I copied and pasted just this part and still the same. there is an unncessary space under the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean about free space under the image, if you're talking about the white space below the x-axis ticks, try adding `ImagePadding -> {{70, 70}, {50, 70.}}` to your plot options.

Comment: what are the parameters of imagepadding?

Comment: okay i see they are just clipping from above and below.